# Issue attaching functionality to MFC Button

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I'm just getting started using MFC to make Windows applications and was hoping someone could help me get the ball rolling on some code with a button I'm trying to write.

What I'm trying to do is build an application that will have a button, that when pressed, will open a modal dialog with some functionality that's not relevant to my question. I'm having trouble getting started because I can't seem to catch when the button is pressed and attach code to that event.

The event added to my message map:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(1, OnBnClicked)
```

This is OnBnClicked:

```
void CMainFrame::OnBnClicked()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this);
  dc.TextOutW(0, 100, _T("SUp dawg"));
  MessageBox(_T("Hey Dawg"));
}
```

Heres the button creation:

```
BOOL bCreated = myButton.Create(_T("Hey Dawg"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
                                 CRect(40, 40, 190, 90), this, 1);
```

I just can't seem to figure out why it won't do anything when I click on it. I appreciate all help with this, it's not particularly well documented online :

Comment: The `BN_CLICKED` notification is sent to the button's immediate parent window, i.e. the window that was passed as the 4th parameter to `Create`. Is `CMainFrame` the button's parent? As an aside, starting Windows programming with MFC is not ever successful. You need to have a solid understanding of the Windows API to even stand a chance to understand MFC. Start with [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx).

Comment: Show more code. In which function do you create the button ?

Comment: Have you ever read TN020? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx — I suspect the numeric identifier (1) of your button is outside of the Valid range! Altough it begins in 8 for controls, I suggest you to try something >=1024.

Comment: More reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041214-00/?p=37013 — Your 1 is in conflict with the `IDOK` identifier, the identifier for the "OK" button. Side Note: the OK and Cancel buttons should not be handled the same way, but on `OnOK()` and `OnCancel()` methods rescpectively.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I'm not going to try to answer your question directly, simply because it's almost unanswerable without seeing (quite a bit) more of what you've done, such as where you put the code that creates the button. Even when/if I did answer the question directly, I doubt the result would be particularly useful. Therefore, I'm going to describe how I'd handle the same basic situation instead.

The basic point I'd make goes back to the single responsibility principle. A window should typically be represented by a class, and that class should have a single responsibility. If that window acts as a control container, then the *sole* responsibility of that class should be to act as a control container.

Most of the time, the class/window that contains the button shouldn't do (much of) anything other than hold buttons (or other controls). In other words, buttons mostly belong in thing like dialogs and toolbars. If you need a display that hosts buttons, you usually want that view to be a CFormView. In this case, the form is built from a dialog template. You can put a button on that dialog template with the dialog editor, just like you would with any other dialog. You attach functionality to it the same way you would to any button in any dialog (shift-click or right-click and select "Add Event Handler...").

Yes, it's possible to do things other ways--neither Visual Studio nor MFC even tries to do much to limit what you can do. That doesn't mean you should ignore basic design though--the single responsibility principle still applies, and it's still important. It's just up to you to enforce it as you design your code--and one of its implications is that you don't just create buttons at random places in the code.